# Filtering with Django endless pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, href, django-endless-pagination

This question has been asked by other people previously and no answers where provided. Effectively, the goal is to implement search functionality with Django's Twitter-style endless pagination. A user modifies some interface field, and the endless table re-initializes taking into account new user inputs.

I have a **template A** which is the main template containing embedded **template B** that serves as container for my endless table. The table loads addition data as the user scrolls down:

```
<select id = 'parameter' class="form-control input-sm">
    <!-- my options -->
</select>
<table>
   <thead>...</thead>
   <tbody>
         {% include 'my_app/template_B.html' %}
   </body>
</table>
```

The structure of template B seems to be irrevelant to the question, so let me omit it.

The Django view which initializes template A:

```
def my_view(request,\
            parameter_id = None,
            template='order_scheduler/template_A.html',\
            extra_context=None):
if parameter_id is None:
   # do smth
else:
   # do smth
return render_to_response(template,
                          context,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request)):
```

The question: How do I reinitialize the endless table in template B when the user modifies the value of parameter combobox without refreshing template A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a view that renders `template_B.html` according to the parameter passed in POST, then in your page:

```
    $(function() {
        var parameter = $('#parameter');
        parameter.on('change', function() {
            $.post("/your/viev/url", {'parameter': parameter.val()}, function(response) {
                $('tbody').html(response);
            });
        });
    });
```